# Issues on EEG PSD feature extraction using signal.welch

Tags: power-spectral-density, scipy, eeg

I am new to EEG signal processing and I am having some issues on calculating PSD using scipy.signal.welch. I am trying to implement a function to extract PSD features. The input of this function is a NumPy array called trials.

Trials is a 3D array that contains EEG data in this form: (trials x time x channels) and I need to calculate PSD for each trial.

The length of Power Spectral Density window is 0.5s
Fs is 512Hz
Overlapping of consecutive PSD windows is 0.5
Frequency bands on which to compute PSD in Hz (4,2,48)

This is what I've done so far but it is throwing errors:

```
from scipy import signal

def PSD(trials):
    psd = []
    pwin = 0.5
    fs = 512
    povl = 0.5
    freqs = [4,2,48]
    for tr in trials:
            f, Pxx = signal.welch(tr, fs=fs, window=pwin, nperseg=None, noverlap=povl,return_onesided=True, scaling='density', axis=- 1, average='mean')
            val, sett = np.intersect1d(f, freqs)
            psd.append(sett)
            
    return psd
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to compute these correctly?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What errors is throwing? Did you read the error message ?

Comment: It does through errors regarding the array size for this row: val, sett = np.intersect1d(f, freqs) but even without intersect it does not compute the PSD features.

Comment: What are the dimensions of `tr` ?

Comment: Since trials is a 3D array, each tr is a 2D array (time x channels)